# Compiling Spring's MVC url pattern regex

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc

I need to be able to turn a list of Spring MVC URL pattern matching expressions into actual Regex Patterns so I can match strings against them.

Example Spring pattern :

```
/actionGroups/{action-group-id:\d+}
```

At the moment if I compile the above string I get a `PatternSyntaxException` because of illegal repetition due to the `{` characters.

Does Spring expose the mechanism it uses to compile/match these string into actual Regex Patterns? It would be cool if I could reuse their functionality.

Else I suppose I'd need to escape the `{` characters manually and strip out the pattern name.. `action-group-id` in this example.

Comment: Look into the implementation of `AntPathMatcher`. I think that's what's used by default.

Comment: Do you escape the backslash in the string literal, i.e. "...\\d+..."?

Comment: Yeah this is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what you are trying to do, check your pattern syntax :

```
@RequestMapping("/actionGroups/{action-group-id:\\d+}")
public void test(@PathVariable(value = "action-group-id") Integer id) {
    // you can use id ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was the AntPathMatcher class i was looking for as per Sotirios Delimanolis's comment above.

This class has a matches method which takes a URL Pattern like the one above and an URL string and returns true/false depending on if the string matches.